# How can I make a loop to remove/skip data/columns in matlab? (for jackknife)

Tags: matlab

I am completely new to matlab and I'm trying to make a jackknife script which basically means that after I bin my data into let's say 40 blocks, I want to make a loop that ignores one block at a time. 
For example I tried something like this

```
let's say R40=randn(5,40) is the matrix
R40_n=R40(:,2:40); reads blocks 2 to 40
R40_n=R40(:,[1:2 4:40]); leaves out block 3
R40_n=R40(:,[1:3 5:40]); leaves out block 4
```

and so on.
How can I make a loop that ignores a block automatically? (I know there is a ready jackknife function but I don't want to use it just yet, before I try making something of my own)
Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: You basically got it. To skip the n-th block use `R40_n=R40(:,[1:n-1 n+1:40]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked, I assume you want a generalised answer that will be applied to any 2D dataset. If that is indeed the case the code below will do the trick.

```
N = 40; % number of sample steps
ix = eye(N); % identity matrix that will allow you to omit one sample step  
R40 = randn(5,40); % your data
for ii=1:N % run over the sample steps
  d = R40(:,~ix(:,ii)); % for each extract all the rows for all the columns except the the one in question 
  % now do whatever you want with the data
end
```

Enjoy